# can argparse store positional number arguments as simple variables?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I would like to use argparse to take some (3) integer arguments, and use these as variables in the program body. Running the code below, each variable gets stored in a one element list. This is no big problem of course, but is it possible to set up the parser to put each value into a simple integer variable?

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='three positional integer arguments.')
    parser.add_argument('picks', type=int, nargs='+', default=10,
                       help='number of selections per execution')
    parser.add_argument('minchunk', type=int, nargs='+', default=2,
                       help='min chunk size')
    parser.add_argument('maxchunk', type=int, nargs='+', default=8,
                       help='max chunk size')

    args = parser.parse_args(['1', '2', '3'])
    print args
    return 0
```

Comment: If you do this, you suddenly get completely differently and incompatible types depending on how many numbers are passed. If you want to support multiple values, just use a list all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nargs = '+'` tells `argparse` to collect 1 or more arguments in a list.
If you remove the `nargs = '+'`:

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description = 'three positional integer arguments.')
    parser.add_argument('picks', type = int, default = 10, nargs = '?',
                       help = 'number of selections per execution')
    parser.add_argument('minchunk', type = int, default = 2, nargs = '?',
                       help = 'min chunk size')
    parser.add_argument('maxchunk', type = int, default = 8, nargs = '?',
                       help = 'max chunk size')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args

main()
```

yields

```
Namespace(maxchunk=3, minchunk=2, picks=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that set me on the right track. Unfortunately with the default value for nargs, the arguments are not optional; if exactly 3 are not supplied, an error is raised (either 'too few arguments', or 'unrecognised arguments'). Using nargs='?' seems to be right option for me, it consumes a single value if one is present, else uses the default value. If more than 3 args are provided, an 'unrecognised arg' error is raised, as appropriate.

Comment: thermalCat, thanks for the feedback. I've added `nargs = '?'` so the defaults have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
(a,b,c) = parser.parse_args(['1','2','3'])
```

Comment: You can even leave out the first set of parentheses if you feel so inclined.